# I want to connect SQL Server 2019 to Unity ? How to get rid off from these errors ? unity 2019.2.11f1

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, connection-string

I have downloaded `.dll` files too and added them to assets folder in `unity2019.2.11f1` but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Have you added them as references in your project?

Comment: Please do not post images of your errors.  The text in images cannot be searched by other users.  Please edit your post and include the error messages _as text_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the .dll files to a "Plugins" folder.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html

Alternatively, you could just set your project's Scripting Runtime Version to ".NET 4.X Equivalent" and all references should be added automatically after Unity restarts.

Comment: I did this but when i drag and drop the script (containing SQL libraries) causing unity freeze.Only in this my unity is hanging or freezing otherwise i didn't observe this issue not in even heavy GPU usage.